# How to join lines between two patterns in sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a json file where I'm wanting to join x number of lines between brackets.

```
cat testfile.json
 {
  "CacheStatistics_ReadHits": 0,
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerPrefetchRemaining": [
   0,
   0
  ],
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerReadMisses": [
   0,
   0
  ]
 }
```

I've tried the following, which should perform the newline replace, first starting at a line ending in '[', and continuing until the closing bracket ']'.

```
sed -i '/\[$/,/\]/ s/\n//g' testfile.json
```

`/\[$/`  searches for line ending in an open bracket.
`/\]/`  continue until closing bracket is reached.
`s/\n//g`  replace newlines with nothing

Resulting file should be:

```
 {
  "CacheStatistics_ReadHits": 0,
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerPrefetchRemaining": [0, 0],
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerReadMisses": [0, 0]
 }
```

Comment: You are wrong assuming `sed` grabs the whole mulitline blocks into pattern space with range patterns. It just goes on reading line by line between start/end delimiters.

Comment: With GNU sed, you may use `sed -i '/\[$/,/]/{:a;$!{N;ba};:b;s/\(\[[^][]*\)\n/\1/g;tb;}' json`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, but GNU sed unfortunately isn't an option for me. I did try something similar to your suggestion, but was not able to debug when it wasn't working. Do you have an answer using BSD sed?

Answer (score 0):

this program will solve your problem. You can save it in a file named: `myprogram.awk`

```
{
if($0 ~ /.*CacheStatistics_ControllerPrefetchRemaining/ ||  $0 ~ /.*CacheStatistics_ControllerReadMisses/){
        datos="";
        gsub("\\n","",$0); datos=datos$0;  
        getline; 
        gsub("\\n","",$0); gsub(" ","",$0); 
        datos=datos$0;
        getline; 
        gsub("\\n","",$0); gsub(" ","",$0); 
        datos=datos$0;
        getline;
        gsub(" ","",$0);  
        datos=datos$0;
        print datos;
}
else
    print $0;
```

You can execute like this:

```
awk -f program.awk testfile.json
```

`testfile.json` are the data that you've posted.

I've got this output:

```
{
  "CacheStatistics_ReadHits": 0,
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerPrefetchRemaining": [0,0],
  "CacheStatistics_ControllerReadMisses": [0,0]
}
```